# What kind of case can I omit?

Tags: android

The following code works well, I often find some sample code to omit, so I change my code as

```
<service android:name=".MyInternetServer"></service>
```

but I get an error "The service can't be found".

I guess the package="com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver" and

```
<service android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.MyInternetServer"></service>,
```

maybe it should be use full name, right?

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.EnableDisableBroadcastReceiver"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_enable_disable_boradcast_receiver" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <!-- Broadcast receiver -->
        <receiver android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.AlarmManagerBroadcastReceiver" >
            <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <service android:name="com.code4reference.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.MyInternetServer"></service>        
    </application>



</manifest>
```

Comment: <service android:name=".MyInternetServer"></service> ..this is enough..because u have already mentioned your package name at the top..it should work...and for activity also use like this..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The shorthand "dot" notation in the Manifest file works [as described in the documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/manifest-intro.html):

> However, as a shorthand, if the first character of the string is a
>   period, the string is appended to the application's package name (as
>   specified by the <manifest> element's package attribute).

So in your case, using:

```
.MyInternetServer
```

...is shorthand for:

```
com.example.enabledisablebroadcastreceiver.MyInternetServer
```

as that's what's in your `<manifest>`'s `package` attribute.

I'm guessing you probably want to update your manifest's package attribute to match the package you're actually using for your project.

Answer (score 0):

Yes give your service a full path, where its actually located with full package name and then check, it will work.